# Add special characters to Uri, Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, uri

So, I have my base URL, which is this:

```
val GITHUB_BASE_URL: String = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories"
```

And then I have this code that appends the param `q (REPO_NAME_PARAM == query)` to the Uri and builds it:

```
val builtUri: Uri = Uri.parse(GITHUB_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
               .appendQueryParameter(REPO_NAME_PARAM, repoName)
               .build()
```

Until here, everything works fine. But, when I try to filter the search of the repositories by the language they are written in (which the URL, for example, should be `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=hello+language:Kotlin`), the `+` and the `:` characters get replaced by `%2B` and `%3A`. This causes the app to not retrieve the expected results, as the characters got changed in the final url.
This is the code that I currently have

```
 val WRITTEN_IN_PARAM: String = "+language:"
 val builtUri: Uri = Uri.parse(GITHUB_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(REPO_NAME_PARAM, repoName+ WRITTEN_IN_PARAM+"Kotlin")
                .build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2B` or not `2B`, that is the question. :)

The problem is that the URL parameter is being URL Encoded twice. When we send certain characters in HTTP queries, they need to be encoded. One encoding (considered a shortcut) is to turn a space into a `+` symbol. The proper way to encode a space is with `%20`.

However, when the code above gets that already encoded String it doesn't know that the `+` is already encoded from a space and tries to encode it again (using `%2B`, the encoding for `+`).

If you hit the URL you've provided with `%20` in place of `+`, and `%3A` in place of `:`, it should work fine. Therefore, the fix is to not send `+` unless you really want a `+`, in which case it will be properly encoded to a `%2B`.

**The Fix:** The library being used appears to correctly encode strings, just leave the `+` as a space and it should give you what you need.

[Here is a good list of characters and their encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), if you are interested.

Comment: But, if I write `%3A` in place of `:` it just returns `%252B`, which `%25` is the encoded form of %

Comment: Don't manually encode anything. Let the library do it for you. Use space and colon directly, the library will encode it for you. Because % is also something that needs to be encoded, and now it's double encoding THAT. Just let the library do all of the encoding.